# AngularJS - get index of last blank element from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var caseOne = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F", ...   ... ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"Admin"}
];

var caseTwo = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F", ...   ... ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    .
    .
    .
    .
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F", ...   ... ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Bat man", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":""}
];
```

I have this kind of array. I want all records after lastIndexOf `"type":""`, means From `cansOne` it'll return last 3 record and from `caseTwo` it'll return 0 record. in short all records after `"type":""`. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

**Expected output**

```
caseOne = [
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M", ...   ... ,"type":"Admin"}
];

caseTwo = [];
```

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Parth Raval, I want last all records which has type. means if last record has `type:""` then it return 0 or if third last record has `type:""` then it'll return last two records.

Comment: @VipulSolanki find the index and splice it. Check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a reusable function `getIndex()` that will take a array parameter and give you the last index of the object with `type: ""`. Using this index you can `splice()` the result and get the desired output

```js
var caseOne = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F" ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M","type":""},
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M","type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M" ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M" ,"type":"Admin"}
];

var caseTwo = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F" ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F","type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M","type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Bat man", "gender":"M","type":""}
];

function getIndex(caseArray){
  var arrayIndex;
  caseArray.forEach(function(caseOneObj, index){
    if(caseOneObj.type === ''){
      arrayIndex = index;
    }
  });
  return arrayIndex;
}

var index = getIndex(caseOne);
var resultCaseOne = caseOne.splice(index+1, caseOne.length);
console.log('-----caseOne-----');
console.log(resultCaseOne);

index = getIndex(caseTwo);
var resultCaseTwo = caseTwo.splice(index+1, caseTwo.length);
console.log('-----caseTwo-----');
console.log(resultCaseTwo);
```

But, if you have array of objects that are most likely to have `type:''` at the last of the array then you can search for that index starting from the last object of that array, like this:

```js
var caseOne = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F" ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M","type":""},
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M","type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M" ,"type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M" ,"type":"Admin"}
];

var caseTwo = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F" ,"type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M" ,"type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F","type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M","type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Bat man", "gender":"M","type":""}
];

function getIndex(caseArray){
  var i;
  for(i=caseArray.length-1; i>0; i--){
   if(caseArray[i].type === ''){
      break;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

var index = getIndex(caseOne);
var resultCaseOne = caseOne.splice(index+1, caseOne.length);
console.log('-----caseOne-----');
console.log(resultCaseOne);

index = getIndex(caseTwo);
var resultCaseTwo = caseTwo.splice(index+1, caseTwo.length);
console.log('-----caseTwo-----');
console.log(resultCaseTwo);
```

Comment: we could change forEach to iterate from the end? and return downwards records this wouldnt be much faster?

Comment: It depends. What if the `type:''` is in first index of array with size 1000. At this time it should loop over 999 records. Both scenario is same, from last or from first. You cannot actually say this is better than that. And we need the index of the last element so both can be opted @PanosK

Comment: @PanosK your point was useful. I edited my answer to include that

Comment: Thanks, exactly I want like your second snippet. both are help full. @Ankit.

Comment: @VipulSolanki glad to help you

Comment: The first version is basically `array.reduce()` : `const index = caseOne.reduce( ( result, next, index ) => next.type ? result : index, 0 );`

Comment: @Shilly Why to use such a complex shorthand when you have a reusable function that is self explanatory

Comment: I don't really think a ternary is that complex to understand. I just mention it because your first function is `array.reduce()` and the second a variant on `array.find()`. So I prefer using the native array methods offered by the language instead of remaking the same functionality again with for loops.

Answer (score 1):

What will getting those array elements this way solve?
Since there's propably a better way than searching through an array to find everything after a certain element.
Anyways, you;re looking for code like:

```js
// source data
const source = [
    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F", "type":"Admin"},
    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M", "type":""},
    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M", "type":""},
    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F", "type":""},
    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M", "type":"User"},
    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M", "type":"User"},
    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M", "type":"Admin"}
];
const lastIndex = Array
 .from( source ) // Clone the array so reversing does not affect the source.
 .reverse() // Reverse the array so we can use findIndex instead of writing findLastIndex ourselves.
 .findIndex( entry => !entry.type ); // Get the index of the first element that has no type.
const result = source.slice( source.length - lastIndex, source.length ); // Slice the orginal array.
console.log( result );
```

Comment: There are two arrays for OP and using this code is duplicated for both the arrays. This cannot be taken as a optimal solution

Comment: Just wrapping it in a function and returning the sliced part will solve that. Anyways, I was trying to help, not diss your own solution if that's how it came across. Can't take back my upvote on your answer now anymore though.

Comment: If you really meant to answer, answer in a appropriate way and make it complete. I hear incompleteness from your previous comment. Anyways I also don't want to diss

Comment: I'll go get us some tequilas and i'll reread the answering rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it like this:

   var caseOne = [
                    {"name":"Felicity", "gender":"F","type":"Admin"},
                    {"name":"Tony", "gender":"M","type":""},
                    {"name":"Super Man", "gender":"M","type":""},
                    {"name":"Wonder Women", "gender":"F","type":""},
                    {"name":"Hulk", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
                    {"name":"Loky", "gender":"M","type":"User"},
                    {"name":"Thore", "gender":"M","type":"Admin"}
                ];
                var result =[];
                var counterIndex = 0;
                for(var i=0; i<caseOne.length; i++) {
                    if(caseOne[i].type == '')
                    counterIndex++;
                }
                result = caseOne.splice(counterIndex+1, caseOne.length);
            console.log(result);
```